# Two or more instances of vimclient

Tags: c#, vmware, vsphere

I'm writing a C# application that needs to access two or more vSphere hosts, not vCenter.  I can connect to all fine and list the VM's but when I query a VM it takes the vimClient information from the last connected vShere host.  Is there a way to retain the VM host information with each VM?

I am using the following to connect to host 1:

```
Client_1.Connect(logon.esxiLogonURL(IP_1.Text));
Client_1.Login(logon.esxiLogonUser(username_1.Text), logon.esxiPassword(password_1.Text));
```

and the following to connect to host 2

```
Client_2.Connect(logon.esxiLogonURL(IP_2.Text));
Client_2.Login(logon.esxiLogonUser(userName_2.Text), logon.esxiPassword(password_2.Text));
```

Any idea on how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Save the connection objects to a List and refer to them later.

`List<VimClient> ConnectionList = new List<VimClient>();`

`Client_1.Connect(logon.esxiLogonURL(IP_1.Text));`
`Client_1.Login(logon.esxiLogonUser(username_1.Text);`
`logon.esxiPassword(password_1.Text));`

`ConnectionList.Add(Client_1);`

`Client_2.Connect(logon.esxiLogonURL(IP_2.Text));`
`Client_2.Login(logon.esxiLogonUser(userName_2.Text);` `logon.esxiPassword(password_2.Text));`

`ConnectionList.Add(Client_2);`

`foreach (VimClient Connection in ConnectionList){ get vmhost information }`